# Taking a screenshot of an Adobe flash player on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I would like to know if there is a method to programmatically take screenshots of a flash object (e.g. TwitchTV video player) and store it temporarily on the server side.

I have done some research on the topic but it seems that it is impossible to do so due to the [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333796/1052746) of Javascript. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no workaround. (Except you are developing an add-on or an extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a month of researching, I found a workaround that works on Chrome. The workaround involves creating a Chrome extension to use a particular extension function called [`captureVisibleTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab).

`captureVisibleTab` produces a screenshot of the visible tab in the form of a `dataUrl`. The resulting `dataUrl` can then be loaded onto a `canvas` element. Once loaded, the canvas can be cropped according to offset specifications (obtainable through content scripts).

See these links:

[captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)

[How to capture a screenshot of a single HTML element in Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309471/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-of-a-single-html-element-in-chrome-extension)

[Chrome Extension API: chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab on Background Page to Content Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794407/chrome-extension-api-chrome-tabs-capturevisibletab-on-background-page-to-conten)

[HTML5 Canvas Image Crop Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/)