# Chrome Extension Take Screenshot of Specific Element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that can take a screenshot of a specific element, however, I am not sure how to take a screenshot ONLY of that element because captureVisibleTab takes a picture of the whole tab.

I tried using getBoundingClientRect to crop the bigger screenshot to the page, however it is giving incorrect values and doesn't work properly.
I also tried using html2canvas however I had trouble using the library in an extension.

Comment: Try [How to capture a screenshot of a single HTML element in Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25732454)

Comment: @wOxxOm , this was my original solution, but upon testing on other devices, this did not work because of aspect ratios and screen resolution.

Comment: Try using [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) to scale the coordinates.